# Remove "there are" to improve sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

can I please get some suggestion on how to improve the following sentence by removing "*there are*"?

> However, there are no unforeseen limitations to apply the framework on
>   other microblogging platforms.

Comment: It's risky to rephrase it without knowing what exactly your sentence means. However, I'd like to try to rephrase it anyway, as an alternative: *The framework can apply to other microblogging platforms as well, without restriction.*

Comment: This previous sentence say, my framework only tested on Twitter, but there should be no unforeseen limitations to apply my framework on other microblogging platform.

Comment: Don't use *unforeseen* here.  *unforeseen* describes things that were not anticipated.  Saying that there are no unforeseen limitations is a bit like saying you know the unknowable.  What you mean to say is that you cannot foresee any limitations that would prevent the application of this framework to other microblogging platforms.

Comment: Why you want to remove it? Does removing it improve the sentence?

Comment: I am learning how to improve my writing, one technique I am very keen is how to remove "There is/there are" and make the sentence more lively.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest,

> Although the framework has been tested only on Twitter, it should work on any microblogging platform.

I found that *"it should be applied on any platform"* sounds a little awkward, so I decided to change *apply* to *work*, and keep *"on Twitter"* and *"on any microblogging platform"* in parallel at the same time.

I thought of three choices: *work*, *run*, and *function*; and *work* is probably the best choice. However, you might have a different opinion because you should know which one works best in your context. (I don't know what your framework is; I guess that it is some kind of software application framework.)

Answer (score 1):

A closer interpretation might be:

*Although only tested on Twitter this framework could, with no apparent limitations, be applied to other microblogging platforms.*

The word you want is the opposite of 'unforseen' therefore 'forseen' (though that is a strange, and uncommon word - so I used apparent (which means seeable, or obvious) instead.  I used only one sentence, instead of two like you did, because the ideas are logically linked, and make better sense this way.

Your framework sounds interesting.  I hope to read the article when you're finished.

Answer (score 0):

I would word it like this:

> However, no unforeseen limitations apply to the framework on other
>   micro-blogging platforms.

I simply took out the **there are** and moved the **to** in front of **apply.**

Hope that helps.